# C++ executing function and lambda inside

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to run similar code to this python code in c++.

```
def f1(a):
    def f2(b):
        return a*b

    return f2
#
if __name__== '__main__':
    x=f1(3)(4)
    print('Result = {0}'.format(x))
```

Output : `Result = 12`

In C++,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <functional>

int f1(int &x)
//should I return lambda from function ? std::function<decltype (...) f1? 
{
    return [x](int &y) ->int
    {return x * y;} ;

}

int main()
{
  int y = { 3 }, z = { 4 };
    int x=f1(y)(z);
    std::cout<<x<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

But I do not know the correct way of doing it. Can someone comment?

Comment: I never knew that python can do that. Though as I understand it returns pointer to function (which is also a function object, but  a named one)  <.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, perhaps?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

std::function<int (int&)> f1 (int& x)
{
    return [x] (int& y) -> int {
        return x * y;
    };
}

int main ()
{
    int y = { 3 }, z = { 4 };
    int x = f1(y)(z);
    std::cout << x << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Since `f1` is a higher-order function, you need to make it return a function. `std::function` wraps anything that can be called as a function with the signature specified in its template parameter into a value that can be passed around, so that's a good candidate for the return type.

Comment: You could also use `auto f1(int& x)` to return a lambda object without the overhead of `std::function` (type erasure, possible dynamic allocation, etc.).

Comment: I am bit confused with `std::function<int (int&)> f1 (int& x)`. `f1` takes `int& x` is clear. But what input and return does `<int (int&)> ` denote?

Comment: @er344tre `int (int&)` is the C++ type of a function taking an int reference and returning an int.

It is passed as a template parameter of `std::function`.

Here is a simple illustration of the mechanism, where the `f` variable is a concrete instance of `Foo`, parameterised by such a function type:

`template < typename T > struct Foo {}; Foo<bool (float, float)> f;`

Comment: @NicolasTisserand, I got the literal meaning of `std::function<int (int&)>`. Sorry for not being clear in previous question. I think `int&` is input parameter for lambda and `int` is return type of `f1`, is that right? In such case, can one write `f1 (int& x,int&y)`? Second one will be input for lambda.

Comment: @er344tre See the alternate answer I just posted. Is this what you meant?

Comment: The `&` in function arguments look like code smell here.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it would look if you want to pass both values to f1:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

std::function<int ()> f1 (int& x, int& y)
{
    return [x, y] () -> int {
        return x * y;
    };
}

int main ()
{
    int y = { 3 }, z = { 4 };
    int x = f1(y, z)();
    std::cout << x << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

In that case, the returned function will not take any parameters when called, since both values have already been captured inside the lambda.